# Using jQuery to use one class when multiple classes are returned

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I am storing a series of classes like so:

```
var sectionParentID = $(this).parent('section').attr('class');
```

The parent has multiple classes. For instance, the above variable might return "`section one titleAdded`" or "`section two titleAdded`" or "`section three titleAdded`"

The class I care about are the numbers: one, two, three, etc. With these numbers, I need to target another div with the same class (one, two, three, etc)

```
var sectionParentSelector =  $(".product_totals").find(" ." + sectionParentID);
```

When I log the selector like so:  `console.log(sectionParentSelector)` it returns the following incorrect selector:

```
.product_totals  .section two titleAdded
```

I need it to return `.product_totals  .two`

What can I do to isolate the class that is needed here?

Comment: The interested class is always the second? In this case you can split it and take the second like http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/c7Pax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var sectionParentID = $(this).parent('section').attr('class');
sectionParentID  = $.trim(sectionParentID.replace(/(section)|(titleAdded)/g, ''))
var sectionParentSelector =  $(".product_totals").find(" ." + sectionParentID);
```